# "brew install hive" failure

Tags: macos, homebrew

Here is what I've got today:

```
myname@mylaptop:~/tmp/123545/ brew install hive
==> Installing dependencies for hive: hadoop
==> Installing hive dependency: hadoop
==> Downloading https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.2/hadoop-3.1.2.tar.gz
==> Downloading from http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.2/hadoop-3.1.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2: 21,686 files, 774.1MB, built in 5 minutes 6 seconds
==> Installing hive
==> Downloading https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hive/hive-3.1.1/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
==> Downloading from http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/hive/hive-3.1.1/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-3.1.1/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-3.1.1/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  DownloadError: Failed to download resource "hive"
Download failed: https://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-3.1.1/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
```

And brew is right: 3.1.1-bin.tar.gz is gone (see the attached image). 
But brew is wrong about not piocking up the 3.1.2....

So my question is: how to tell brew to pick up the new version? 
Thank you in advance!

PS: oops, cannot upload an image, but basically it's the screenshot of this: 
https://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/

PSS: I cannot add tags "hive" and "install": c'mon guys, this is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit brew formula and configure it for Hive version you would like to install. To do so, run:

```
brew edit hive
```

You need to update **url** and **sha256** fields. If you want to install Hive v3.1.2 your formula should look like this:

```
class Hive < Formula
  desc "Hadoop-based data summarization, query, and analysis"
  homepage "https://hive.apache.org"
  url "https://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-3.1.2/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin.tar.gz"
  sha256 "d75dcf36908b4e7b9b0ec9aec57a46a6628b97b276c233cb2c2f1a3e89b13462"
```

You can find latest Hive version here:
https://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/

Than go ahead and run

```
brew install hive
```

Hope that helps